# Hypothesis Testing of Comparison of $2$ Treatments

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

A blanching process currently used in the canning industry consists of treating vegetables with a large volume of boiling water before canning. A newly developed method, called Steam Blanching Process (SBP), is expected to remove less vitamins and minerals from vegetables, because it is more of a steam wash than a flowing water wash. Ten batches of string beans from different farms are to be used to compare the SBP and the standard process. One-half of each batch of beans is treated with the standard process; the other half of each batch is treated with the SBP. Measurements of the vitamin content per pound of canned beans are:

```
SBP Standard
35 33
48 40
65 55
33 41
61 62
54 54
49 40
37 35
58 59
65 56
```

a) Do the data provide strong evidence that SBP removes less vitamins in canned beans than the standard method of blanching? Use t-test and sign-test.

b) Construct a $98$% confidence interval for the difference between the mean vitamin contents per pound using the two methods of blanching.

**Attempted Solution**

a)

**t-test**

$H_0$: $\delta$ = $0$

$H_1$: $\delta$ $\gt$ $0$

Average difference $\bar{D}$ = $3$

$S_D$ = $5.8689$

t = $\frac{\bar{D}-\delta_0}{S_D\over{\sqrt{n}}}$ = $1.616$

$t_{9, .05}$ = $1.83313$

Since $1.616 \lt 1.833113$ we fail to reject $H_0$ at $\alpha = .05$

**Sign Test**

Proportion of positive $D_i$'s = $2\over3$

$P(X \geq 6)$ = $.5^{9}$[$9\choose{6}$ + $9\choose{7}$ + $9\choose{8}$ + $9\choose{9}$]

= $.254 \gt .05$ so we fail to reject $H_0$ at $\alpha = .05$

b) $\bar{D}$ $\pm$ $t_{n-1, \alpha/2}$$\frac{S_D}{\sqrt{n}}$

=$3$ $\pm$ $t_{9, .01}$$\frac{5.8689}{\sqrt{10}}$

= $(-2.236, 8.236)$

Did I do these correctly? Particularly the sign test?

Comment: This looks good, except the sign test. Where does 9 come from? There are 10 batches.

Comment: I thought you were supposed to ignore the batches with a difference of 0?

Comment: Ah, you excluded a tie. Then everything looks good for me.